# Difference between tar and star

Tags: tar

I've been learning about the syntax and usage of `tar` and came across `star`.

I've read this paragraph from the `star` manpage:

> Star includes the first free implementation of POSIX.1-2001 extended tar headers. The POSIX.1-2001 extended tar headers define a new standard way for going beyond the limitations of the historic tar format. They allow (among others) to archive all UNIX time stamps in sub-second resolution, files of arbitrary size and filenames without length limitation using UNICODE UTF-8 coding for best exchange compatibility.

and **I'm wondering if this still remains true at the present time**, or whether `tar` has caught up in this aspect.

Most of the documentation that I've found is at least a decade old. I've also looked at the `tar` changelog over the last 10 years and can't find anything that states that it follows the above "extended tar headers".

Comment: You didn't even include your version of RH/Centos.

Comment: @Pavel Šimerda: you can assume the latest, but the question is more about `tar`version here.

Comment: @Ouki: I would rather not assume in this case. And the versions of packages depend on the version of the distribution.

Comment: I've removed the rhel/centos tags, since it's not important what OS it is on. I'm asking about the programs `tar` & `star` themselves. I'm mainly trying to find out if they are any different, or if that was just the case 10-12 years ago.

Comment: (on a phone, can't put in a real answer) check the GNU tar info page, there is a section about tar formats... It supports several, and explains the differences.

Comment: Today, after many years gtar did add some of the star features. There is still no builtin find and if you extract arcihives with some aclsusing gtar, this is a security risk. Acls in gtar are only implemented for linux and there is no support for the acl standard but only for the draft that was withdrawn in 1997.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By comparing these two pages<sup>1,2</sup> I found the following:

- `tar` supports the POSIX.1-2001 extended tar headers, you can specify this format using
  the `--posix` switch or `--format=posix`
- `tar` also supports a `diff` command using `--diff` or `--compare`, similar to `star`.
- I couldn't find any significant differences between `tar` and `star`...

... So I guess I can lay my mind to rest.

---

<sup>1: http://linux.die.net/man/1/star

2: http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html</sup>

Comment: Tar does not support -diff at all, gtar implements a very simplified variant of the star -diff feature as gtar does not compare all metadata and does not allow to control what to compare.

Comment: Also don't forget that many switches are different, you can't simply replace tar with star and keep the rest of your command line

Comment: A common mistake from people on Linux is to confuse `tar` with `gtar`. While `star` (when called as `tar`) is 100% compatible to `tar`, `gtar` is incompatible. As a result people on Linux learn `gtar` and believe they learned `tar`. I even believe that the incompatibilities between `star` and `gtar` did not happen if the `gtar` people first checked for similar `star` enhancements before introducing own incompatible variants.